# Is there a way to log results of a script in JS or python?

Tags: javascript, python, google-chrome, genetic-algorithm

I have a project where I have to open a page (from my computer), have that tab open a JS file, and read the results of the JS file. I need the python script to read the console output, then close the site. Right now, the code I use to open the site is

```
webbrowser.open('index.html', new=2)
```

and the website code is

```
<script src="codefile.js"></script>
<script>close();</script>
```

Comment: No, you can't do that directly. What you are actually trying to do exactly?

Comment: I am trying to read the console output with python.

Comment: Why do you open this page? Is there no other way?

Comment: I need to run a JS file, and that file could contain bad code, and browsers have safeguards to stop bad code/ code that would interfere with the other code, and I cannot use a VM due to my pc not having space.

Comment: You can get the output of this code and send it using `fetch` to your python server